# How can I use a separate domain for URL shortening?

Tags: domain, urls

I have a hosted Wordpress blog running on my own domain. I've recently considered trying to build a custom URL shortener (a la bit.ly) that I manage and control using a very short domain. I'm wondering how I can achieve this.

For example:

I want this: http://nerdgap.com/some-made-up-post-here/

To shorten to this: http://g4p.it/23  (where 23 is the Worpress post ID).

Is this possible? How can I go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try [Yourls](http://yourls.org/). I hadn't used it myself but feedback I seen is very positive and it is project by very known developers (Lester Chan and Ozh).

Answer (score 2):

You already get shortlinks of the form `?p=post_id`, so [`http://nerdgap.com/?p=66`](http://nerdgap.com/?p=66) points to [`http://nerdgap.com/great-big-update-plus-giveaway/`](http://nerdgap.com/great-big-update-plus-giveaway/). You could exploit this by creating a simple redirection from `http://g4p.it/{$post_id}` to `http://nerdgap.com/?p={$post_id}`.

You can then integrate this in your editor (the *"Get Shortlink"* button) and add a `<link rel="shortlink">` in your header by hooking into the [`pre_get_shortlink`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2176) filter, and returning `http://g4p.it/{$post_id}`.